# DatePickerDialog resets to default month when changing selectableDays

Tags: android, materialdatepicker

I have a DatePickerDialog (com.wdullaer.materialdatetimepicker.date) that has its selectableDays populated from an API.
The API that we use only supports retrieving one month at a time. As a result, we need to retrieve more selectableDays for the next month when the user taps the arrow to go to the next month. (Circled in red in the attached image)

[image: Arrow To Change Months]

We accomplish this by keeping a global list of calendars and adding additional Calendars from the network responses:

```
val selectableCalendars = HashSet<Calendar>() // List of available appointment dates (including time)
```

That works fine, but when **DatePickerDialog is open** and the following line runs to change the selectable days:

```
datePickerDialog.selectableDays = selectableCalendars.toTypedArray()
```

The DatePickerDialog will jump back to the first month in the calendar list.

This "jump back to June" (unintended behavior) always occurs under the following circumstances:

> 1.) Immediately after we set datePickerDialog.selectableDays to a new value.

> 2.) Only if there are no selectable days for the month the user scrolled into. (Bug does not occur if there are selectable days in the
> returned month!)

Does anyone have a workaround for this issue?

Answer (score 1):

By checking the code here

https://github.com/wdullaer/MaterialDateTimePicker/blob/f849a5c2704c974ba182fe4e2e205fa7f4fd395d/library/src/main/java/com/wdullaer/materialdatetimepicker/date/DatePickerDialog.java#L846

It seems that after you set new selectableDays, the refresh function will take current selected day position and scroll back to it https://github.com/wdullaer/MaterialDateTimePicker/blob/f849a5c2704c974ba182fe4e2e205fa7f4fd395d/library/src/main/java/com/wdullaer/materialdatetimepicker/date/DayPickerView.java#L142

So my proposal will be setting the `mSelectedDay` to the first day of the month when user scoll to the next month. Which I think also not a great user experience.

I would also recommend to post this question on author's github page, or search for similar question/issue/bug history in the library github pag

Comment: As recommended, I [opened an issue on their github page](https://github.com/wdullaer/MaterialDateTimePicker/issues/743)
I cannot set mSelectedDay for my case because the user is currently looking at a month that does not have any selectable dates within it, as mentioned in #2.) above.